# Find ${{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}}$ when $x = {1 \over {t + 1}}$ and $y = {1 \over {t - 1}}$

Tags: calculus

The answer in the text book is:
${{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} = 4{\left( {{{t + 1} \over {t - 1}}} \right)^3}$

I've tried this:

$\eqalign{
  & x = {1 \over {t + 1}},y = {1 \over {t - 1}}  \cr 
  & x = {(t + 1)^{ - 1}},y = {(t - 1)^{ - 1}}  \cr 
  & {{dx} \over {dt}} =  - {(t + 1)^{ - 2}} = {{ - 1} \over {{{(t + 1)}^2}}}  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dt}} =  - {(t - 1)^{ - 2}} = {{ - 1} \over {{{(t - 1)}^2}}}  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} = {{dy} \over {dt}} \times \left( {{1 \over {{{dx} \over {dt}}}}} \right)  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dx}} = {{ - 1} \over {{{(t - 1)}^2}}} \times {{{{(t + 1)}^2}} \over { - 1}} = {{{{(t + 1)}^2}} \over {{{(t - 1)}^2}}} \cr} $

---

My approach to ${{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}}$ is:
$${{dy} \over {dx}} = {{{{(t + 1)}^2}} \over {{{(t - 1)}^2}}}$$
So using the quotient rule:

$\eqalign{
  & u = {(t + 1)^2}  \cr 
  & v = {(t - 1)^2}  \cr 
  & {{du} \over {dt}} = 2(t + 1)  \cr 
  & {{dv} \over {dt}} = 2(t - 1)  \cr 
  & {{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} = {{2{{(t - 1)}^2}(t + 1) - 2{{(t + 1)}^2}(t - 1)} \over {{{(t - 1)}^4}}}  \cr 
  & {{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} = {{2(t - 1)(t + 1)\left[ {(t - 1) - (t + 1)} \right]} \over {{{(t - 1)}^4}}}  \cr 
  & {{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} = {{2(t - 1)(t + 1)( - 2)} \over {{{(t - 1)}^4}}}  \cr 
  & {{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} = {{ - 4(t + 1)} \over {{{(t - 1)}^3}}} \cr} $

---

As the previous attempt yielded an incorrect answer I attempted to answer it this way:

$\eqalign{
  & {{dx} \over {dt}} =  - {(t + 1)^{ - 2}}  \cr 
  & {{dy} \over {dt}} =  - {(t - 1)^{ - 2}}  \cr 
  & {{{d^2}x} \over {d{t^2}}} = 2{(t + 1)^{ - 3}}  \cr 
  & {{{d^2}y} \over {d{t^2}}} = 2{(t - 1)^{ - 3}} \cr} $

$\eqalign{
  & {{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} = {{{d^2}y} \over {d{t^2}}} \times \left( {{1 \over {{{{d^2}x} \over {d{t^2}}}}}} \right)  \cr 
  & {{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} = {2 \over {{{(t - 1)}^3}}} \times {{{{(t + 1)}^3}} \over 2}  \cr 
  & {{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}} = {{{{(t + 1)}^3}} \over {{{(t - 1)}^3}}} \cr} $

---

I'd appreciate it greatly if someone could point out my misunderstanding(s) and show me the correct approach.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have computed $\frac{dy}{dx}$. That's a good start.

In your first attempted calculation of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, you actually calculated $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$. That's good, but we want the derivative of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ **with respect to** $x$, not with respect to $t$.

Easily fixed! Multiply by $\frac{dt}{dx}$, or equivalently divide by $\frac{dx}{dt}$. You used that "trick" already, just use it once more. All of the ingredients you need are present in your first attempt.

**Remark:** There is no easy fix I can think of for the second attempt. Even though it is true that $\frac{dz}{dw}$ is the reciprocal of $\frac{dw}{dz}$, it is **not** in general true that  $\frac{d^2 z}{dw^2}$ is the reciprocal of $\frac{d^2 w}{dz^2}$.

Why can't you take the reciprocal? Because when you "flip," the $2$'s end up in the wrong places! By the way, just in case of misunderstanding, the "explanation" in the preceding sentence  is a **joke**.

Comment: I see, I was thinking it odd that I was differentiating and despite the notation being ${{{d^2}y} \over {d{x^2}}}$ that it was not in terms of x. So if I have understood you want me to do this: ${d \over {dt}}\left( {{{dy} \over {dx}}} \right) \times {{dt} \over {dx}}$ ?

Comment: I must admit, I'm still a little confused.

Comment: Take the thing in your calculation that you called $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$, and which is actually $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx}($. Divide by $\frac{dx}{dt}$. The right answer will pop up.

Comment: Thank you Andre, I'll go and make sense of all this now.
I know this has probably been asked before, but what textbook do you recommend for calculus? In the current one I'm studying the calculus section is only a small section, and it teaches you calculus in a relatively mechanical way (i.e. it's just some operation you do), do you know of any text book you could recommend that are east to grasp and cover the foundations relatively well?

Comment: There is nothing I would particularly recommend. Any of the big North American type calculus books has lots of examples. *Stewart* is pretty good of this style. So is *Adams*. But these books are disgustingly expensive. Out of date copies are sometimes available cheaply as used books. There must also be lots of free good stuff on the Web. Perhaps you can ask a question about that.

Answer (score 3):

As André said, your first computation was almost right, but $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\mathrm{d} x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t}\right)^{-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\frac{\mathrm{d} t}{\mathrm{d} x}$$

---

I just thought your second attempt is worth talking about - the problem is $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} \neq \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} t^2}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d} t^2}}$$

Let's quickly look at $y=t^2$, $x=t$. Then $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} t^2} t^2 = 2$$ Everything goes wrong when you see that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d} t^2} = 0$$

Obviously looking at the second derivative isn't enough!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the implicit approach, we could write $y$ in terms of $x,$ then translate back into terms of $t$ at the end. Take $t\neq\pm 1$. Since $$x=\frac1{t+1},$$ then $$t+1=\frac1x,$$ so $$t-1=\frac1x-2=\frac{1-2x}{x},$$ and so $$y=\frac1{t-1}=\frac{x}{1-2x}.$$ Now, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(1-2x)-(-2)x}{(1-2x)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}=(1-2x)^{-2},$$ so $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-2\cdot(1-2x)^{-3}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}[1-2x]=\frac4{(1-2x)^3},$$ and since $y=\frac{x}{1-2x},$ then $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=4\cdot\frac{y^3}{x^3}=4\left(\frac yx\right)^3.$$ Finally, recalling that $x=\frac1{t+1}$ and $y=\frac1{t-1},$ it follows that $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=4\left(\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right)^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use this: If $x(t),y(t)$ are differentiable functions of $t$ and $x'(t)\neq 0$, then
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}. $$
For this problem $x(t)=\frac{1}{t+1},y(t)=\frac{1}{t-1}$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}=\frac{-\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}}{-\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}}=\frac{(t+1)^2}{(t-1)^2}=\left(\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right)^2
\end{eqnarray*}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{\frac{-4(t+1)}{(t-1)^3}}{-\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}}=\frac{(t+1)^3}{(t-1)^3}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: That's a nice explanation, thank you